# Referring to nested object in controller through Angular expression

Tags: angularjs, object, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

A quick challenge for all you angular wiz out there.

Say in my controller I have something like

```
app.controller('testController', 
  function ($scope) {
    preWrittenFunction1 (function callBack () {
      preWrittenFunction2 {function callBack2 () {
        $(this).data = {JSON data};
      });
    });
});
```

How would I go about to access the data object in an expression? If in the initial scope, it can be accessed via

```
<html block>{{testController.data}}</html block>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of preWrittenFunctions?

Comment: Is that relevant to solving the question?

Comment: Do you mean ( instead of { in 'preWrittenFunction2 (function callBack2 () {' instead of 'preWrittenFunction2 {function callBack2 () {'

Comment: this question makes no sense...

Comment: My apologies, I should add that the preWrittenFunction1 and 2 are from a function library I have written. The parameter is a callback function which are seen in callBack and callBack2. I am merely looking for a way to access the data object in my controller via an expression. Thanks again :)

Comment: just do $scope.data = {JSON data} inside your controller.  Then do <div>{{data}}</div> in your HTML

Comment: However I require it to be nested in the two functions because they are pertinent to the data. Without the two functions being declared, the data cannot be accessed properly. Think of them as the keys to unlocking the data. And only when unlocked can the data be accessed.

Comment: I was under the impression that Angular was suppose to be smooth and beautiful... guess I was wrong :/ Is there really no way of getting deeper into the scope of a controller with expressions?

Comment: Using a framework wrong does not make the framework bad. If you want to access data from a template, you put it on `$scope`, not on the controller instance.

Comment: @ivarni how would I go about what I am doing now the right way in Angular? Please tell. I need to modify the data with the two functions and the second needs to be in the callback of the first.

Comment: @dapirate7 I am thinking the solution will be Javascript than Angular. Please add some plnkr. Also add a bit of few lines why you have to do the way you are doing than simple normal way of using AngularJS. That will help us.

Comment: I think you are confused between AngularJS' scope and JavaScript's scope